# Declaring "private" vars within an angular service is a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On their [guide page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) I saw an example of creating a custom service:

```
angular.
module('myServiceModule', []).
 controller('MyController', ['$scope','notify', function ($scope, notify) {
   $scope.callNotify = function(msg) {
     notify(msg);
   };
 }]).
factory('notify', ['$window', function(win) {
   var msgs = [];
   return function(msg) {
     msgs.push(msg);
     if (msgs.length == 3) {
       win.alert(msgs.join("\n"));
       msgs = [];
     }
   };
 }]);
```

This service has a "private/hidden" array `var msgs = [];` (that can not be read when the service is injected in `MyController` ). This array is then updated by the controller using `notify(msg);`

If, for some reason, I want to inject this service in another controller, let's say `MyController2`, then these two controllers will update the same array. So, based on this case, is this a bad practice to use a private var like so? or this is the way that services were built to act like?

I know that I can store the array on the contructor function (`this.msgs = []`) and then in the controller to create a new notify(), but what is the best practice?

Comment: There are no best practice. It depends on what you want. If I want tracks all the notifyand, for example, at the tenth write on db, then that code it's ok.

Comment: there is no *one-size-fits-all* answer. In some cases exposing the array may make it easier to bind inheritance all the way through to the view. Depends on use case

Comment: and you want to say that I can use a service to communicate one with each other or not?